# Merge and transpose dataframes out of the outcome of a function

Tags: r

I have the following function:

```
tables <- lapply(unique(dfdeciles$newname), function(group) {
  table <- percentage_data %>%
    filter(newname == group) %>%
    select(decile, percentage)
  
  assign(paste0("table_", group), table, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  
  return(table)
})
```

which return me x number of tables which look like that in which the column newname and percentage change for each table.

```
structure(list(newname = c("Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", 
"Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", 
"Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", "Energy", 
"Energy", "Energy"), decile = 1:20, percentage = c(0.000955339878795954, 
0.000251405231262093, 0.00558464004129603, 0.00108551957388783, 
0.00615563986791596, 0.0170246112359045, 0.00811797823467131, 
0.123014301610181, 0.0170259887988156, 0.397938664452207, 0.333016879581413, 
2.28597197656832, 2.56482239370676, 10.5743347686712, 2.68008928150534, 
6.72136638371249, 8.5249667986675, 13.4595955150188, 14.7015855721555, 
37.5770963414877)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    newname = "Energy", .rows = structure(list(1:20), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

I would like to add to the function a way to transpose and merge the tables that produces as outcome so that the names of the rows in the new tables are the name in the first column of each table, the headers are the values of column 2(decile) and the values of the new table are the values of each table in column percentage

I can't go further than that so far

Comment: I'm not sure if we're missing `percentage_data` or `dfdeciles`, but we don't have both.